# Setting downloads directory for chrome driver suddenly stopped working after upgrade

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After I've upgraded my project to use latest java selenium webdriver 3.7.1 and latest chrome driver 2.33 I noticed that my tests dealing with Excel export started to fail.

After debugging I see that for some reasons downloads directory is not being set to custom location and instead the default one is used. Nothing shows up in logs or whatsoever.

Any help appreciated.

Setting downloads directory is like usual:

```
    val prefs = Map(
      "profile.default_content_settings.popups" -> Integer.valueOf(0),
      "download.default_directory" -> downloadsDir,
      "credentials_enable_service" ->  false,
      "profile.password_manager_enabled" -> false
    )
    val chromeOptions:ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)
    val d = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use WebDriver 3.7.1 and Chromedriver 2.33 and of course Chrome v.62 (try check Your Version of Chrome), and I can download files.

I'm using folder

```
public static String javaIoTmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"/autotest/";
```

and I create/clean it with script in TestNG annotation: @BeforeSuite

```
File theDir = new File(javaIoTmpDir);
    // if the directory does not exist, create it
    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        System.out.println("creating directory: " + theDir.getName());
        boolean result = false;
        try{
            theDir.mkdir();
            result = true;
        }
        catch(SecurityException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(result) {
            System.out.println(javaIoTmpDir+" created");
        }
    }
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(javaIoTmpDir));
    }
```

Comment: I have 62.0.3202.94 version of Chrome.
The problem is with this line of code in initializing chrome driver instance stopped to have any effect: `prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadsDir)`. It broke on both linux and windows boxes.

Comment: My options for chrome in BrowserFactory.java are:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   HashMap<String, Object> chromePref = new HashMap<>();
   chromePref.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
   chromePref.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
   options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePref);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Comment: Hmm... but I don't see where you set up that `theDir` will be the downloads folder for the Chrome instance your suite will run. Or I miss some point?

Comment: I mean do your tests  dowlnload some files from that browser?

Comment: U use default setting of browser, so downloaded files are in /Download/ dir.
I clean it before every test suite (in annotation TestNG @BeforeSuite) I added: 
`String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
  try {
   FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(home + "/Downloads/"));
  }  catch (Exception e) {
   FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(home + "/Pobrane/")); //'Download' in Polish language
  } `

Comment: I see. I need to use custom directory. So I used that `download.default_directory` preference in Chrome options but it's not working anymore. I think I will need to file a ticket.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar have you filed a bug for this ? i see the same issue